# Gradle composite build throwing "Failed to get Gradle name for :module"

Tags: gradle

We've a collection of libraries developed by different teams and individually pushed to different Git repositories. To minimize the hassle of publishing to local Maven repositories or publishing snapshot versions, we've put together a root project to include all those libraries with Gradle's dependencies substitutions.

The structure is as follows:

```
- root (Git-root)
  ...
  - modules
    - module-a (Git-module-a)
      - a-core
        - build.gradle.kts
      - a-data
        - build.gradle.kts
      - settings.gradle.kts
    - module-b (Git-module-b)
      - b-core
        - build.gradle.kts
      - b-data
        - build.gradle.kts
      - settings.gradle.kts
    - settings.gradle.kts
  - settings.gradle.kts
```

It's a bit confusing but `module-a` and `module-b` are included as git submodules inside a `modules` folder of the `root` project.

The Gradle files are as follow:

settings.gradle.kts

```
rootProject.name = "project-root"
includeBuild("modules")
```

modules/settings.gradle.kts

```
rootProject.name = "modules"
includeBuild("module-a")
includeBuild("module-b")
```

modules/module-a/settings.gradle.kts

```
rootProject.name = "module-a"
include("a-core")
include("a-data")
```

modules/module-b/settings.gradle.kts

```
rootProject.name = "module-b"
include("b-core")
include("b-data")
```

Just to illustrate the reason for this, lets say that the `module-b:b-core` depends on the `module-a:a-core` library.

The problem is that when I run this build it comes back with the following message:

```
Multiple build operations failed.
    Failed to get Gradle name for :a-core
    Failed to get Gradle name for :a-data
    Failed to get Gradle name for :b-core
    Failed to get Gradle name for :b-data
```

I don't know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation. It looks like we're always very close to what we desire, but it's almost impossible to get there.

Do you guys know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Error messsages come from AGP `ModelBuilder.getBuildName()`
The reason is that most "bottom" projects in composite build ("a-core", "a-data", "b-core" and "b-data") have `gradle.rootProject.parent` set to "topmost" project ("project-root"), instead of their immediate parents ("module-a" and  "module-b").
You can check it putting
`println("${project.name} parent is ${project.gradle.parent?.rootProject?.name}")`
in build.gradle.kts of all the projects and running sync

It whether Gradle or AGP problem, depending on is such a `root` behavior correct or a gradle bug.
I have created [the issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/23837) about this case in gradle project. Will look what gradle team answer :)

As temporary solution add `includeBuild("a-core")` and other bottom level projects in `modules/settings.gradle.kts`. If still will got error, try add it to the topmost "project-root" `settings.gradle.kts` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. I'll follow that issue on GitHub and tryout your suggestions as soon as possible.

Comment: Gradle team say this is not bug, but feature :) https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/23837#issuecomment-1438029860 So, it's AGP bug. We should address Google.

Comment: Have posted issue to Google https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/278096743